# Search engines for academic jobs

Tags: mathematics, computer-science, job-search

I have recently started looking for academic jobs search engines. There are some good ones for Math already listed in this site (for instance https://www.mathjobs.org/jobs?employers---m, https://euromathsoc.org/jobs). I have both a background in Math and Computer Science but a soon to be PhD in Computer Science. Are there any such search engines for academic jobs in Computer Science?

I'm trying google jobs but somehow I only get new jobs in my current country or its neighbour. So the second question would be, is there a way to tweak google jobs to show jobs in all the world and not just your current location?

Comment: Are academic jobs special in that sense? I would say that academic jobs that are publicly advertised are covered by the usual job search portals where you also look for other jobs, aren't they? You have to adjust your search parameters accordingly.

Comment: You may want to provide a country or a region as a tag or in the question. Otherwise I suspect this might vary too much internationally to give a good answer.

Comment: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/7498276?hl=en-CH&visit_id=638156075739206809-964378889&p=job_search&rd=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this support webpage to do so

https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/7498276?hl=en-CH&visit_id=638156075739206809-964378889&p=job_search&rd=1